# PyInstaller fails on wine

Tags: python, pyinstaller, wine

I am trying to cross compile python-programs to windows executables. I am running debian 11 on a VM, because all threads regarding this topic used a debian/ubuntu based system. After a lot of trial and error, I got python and pip to work on wine and PyInstaller installed, but I am running into a problem now:

When trying to compile a test script (`wine python.exe -m PyInstaller HALLOWELT.py`) PyInstaller throws the following error: `File "Z:\home\benedikt\Downloads\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 84, in create_py3_base_library with open(mod.filename, 'rb') as fs: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Z:\\home\\benedikt\\Downloads\\python310.zip\\_collections_abc.pyc'`

I can post the full traceback if needed. Another confusing point is, that if I deflate the python310.zip in a seperate dir, there is, in fact, the _collections_abc.pyc package existent.

I have the suspicion, that this has something to do with the slash and backslash syntax, because _collections_abc.pyc seems to be the first package to be requested in the respective file within Pyinstaller. But this is just a theory, not based on much.

Any help on how to get rid of this error and make the cross-compiling finally work would be greatly appreciated. Maybe change something in the PyInstaller scripts? But what and where? Or would this generally be a question for the Unix&Linux Stack Exchange instead? I'll post any further information if you need it.